# User profile image update from a popup window

Tags: 7, media, users, modal-dialogs

Is there a way to make the user profile image updated using overlay window from different page other than /user/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Profile Pic Changer](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_pic_changer) Module Provides a modal dialog box to change user pictures

> Allow users to change their profile picture through a modal form
>   directly on their profile page, without having to go to the profile
>   edit form.

Comment: @pravin-ajaaz It does not work with panels.